# Is any version of Internet Explorer supports Javascript generators?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

It's not clear if any version of Internet Explorer supports Javascript Generators. Does IE10 supports it ?

Comment: Please give an example of a _generator_ so we know if you're talking about _ECMAScript 6_ or _JavaScript 1.7 (the largely unsupported ES4)_. Either way, _Mozilla_ browsers are the most likely to support it by default, with other browsers having no implementation or requiring special flags for it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**. None of the IE versions support as of now.

Please check the compatibility table http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#Generators_(yield)

Comment: This is what I was looking for : Generators yield. Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't give a code example, I'm assuming you're talking about the concept of generators and not a specific feature.

You can write generators for any browser if you factor your code for it, for example

```
function MakeFibGenerator() {
    var prv = 1, cur = 0;   // let values required in logic have colsure above
    return function fib() { // the logic function, which is returned
        return cur = prv + (prv = cur);
    }
} // this could have been done as an IIFE

var myGen = MakeFibGenerator();

myGen(); /* 1 */ myGen(); // 1
myGen(); /* 2 */ myGen(); // 3
myGen(); /* 5 */ myGen(); // 8
```